# highcharts column stacking Y axis sync - value seem to be represented as an increase on that of previous column

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I have the following chart (pic below)

Am i understanding stacking incorrectly? shouldn't the y-Axis value range be `[-12, -1]`?

[image: current result]

instead highcharts seems to add to the value of the previous column for a category when drawing the stack,
ending up with -5.3 + (-9.2) + (-12.0) + (-6.7) = -33.2 and hence drawing the column up to a 33.2 y axis coordinate instead of stacking all the smaller values inside `-12.0`.

here's my config

my data is sorted by `y` (see code below), highcharts' documentation mentions

> When stacking is enabled, data must be sorted in ascending X order.

```
{
    "chart": {
        "styledMode": false,
        "backgroundColor": "transparent",
        "spacing": [10, 5, 0, 0],
        "width": null,
        "height": "38%",
        "style": { "fontFamily": "inherit" }
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "area": { "marker": { "enabled": false } },
        "spline": { "marker": { "enabled": false } },
        "line": { "marker": { "enabled": false } },
        "series": { "enableMouseTracking": true },
        "column": {
            "stacking": "normal",
            "dataLabels": { "enabled": true, "inside": true, "format": "{point.y:,.1f}", "style": { "fontWeight": "normal" } }
        }
    },
    "navigation": { "buttonOptions": { "enabled": false } },
    "xAxisConfig": {
        "xAxisOptions": {
            "min": 0.5,
            "startOnTick": false,
            "endOnTick": false,
            "minPadding": 0,
            "maxPadding": 0,
            "gridLineWidth": 0,
            "labels": {
                "style": {
                    "color": "#8095aa",
                    "lineHeight": "16px",
                    "textTransform": "uppercase",
                    "letterSpacing": "1.2px",
                    "fontSize": "10px",
                    "fontWeight": "normal"
                }
            },
            "categories": [
                "IGA",
                "LPD",
                "LTK",
                "MAN",
                "PTE",
                "VAL",
                "VAM",
                "VAS",
                "VBA",
                "VBS",
                "VEB",
                "VES",
                "VIC",
                "VIA",
                "VIC",
                "VIL",
                "VAS",
                "VTM"
            ],
            "max": 17
        }
    },
    "yAxisConfig": {
        "yAxisOptions": {
            "opposite": false,
            "gridLineColor": "#8095aa",
            "gridLineDashStyle": "Dot",
            "title": { "text": null },
            "offset": -10,
            "startOnTick": false,
            "minPadding": 0,
            "maxPadding": 0,
            "labels": { "style": { "color": "#8095aa", "lineHeight": "16px", "letterSpacing": "0.3px", "fontSize": "12px", "fontWeight": "normal" } },
            "tickPixelInterval": 20,
            "min": null,
            "max": null
        }
    },
    "colors": ["#9bd9a8", "#f9b36c", "#9ea2a5", "#95b3e1", "#cea3a6"],
    "series": [
        {
            "data": [
                { "y": -7.55234464138288, "tooltipLabel": "PTE" },
                { "y": -6.26724628978681, "tooltipLabel": "VAS" },
                { "y": -3.58044975748122, "tooltipLabel": "VAS" },
                { "y": -3.37783607784082, "tooltipLabel": "VBA" },
                { "y": -3.1935940773000002, "tooltipLabel": "VIC" },
                { "y": -0.2846235546, "tooltipLabel": "VIL" },
                { "y": -0.1796231514, "tooltipLabel": "VTM" },
                { "y": -0.0666363456, "tooltipLabel": "MAN" },
                { "y": -0.0464127807, "tooltipLabel": "VES" },
                { "y": -0.0160181769, "tooltipLabel": "VBS" },
                { "y": -0.0086822076, "tooltipLabel": "VAL" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "IGA" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "LPD" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "LTK" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VAM" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VEB" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIA" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIC" }
            ],
            "label": "Q2 19",
            "name": "Q2 19",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#9bd9a8",
            "dashStyle": "Solid",
            "lineType": "Solid",
            "marker": {},
            "connectNulls": true
        },
        {
            "data": [
                { "y": -6.70349414707873, "tooltipLabel": "PTE" },
                { "y": -5.86808436147698, "tooltipLabel": "VAS" },
                { "y": -4.03754309365603, "tooltipLabel": "VAS" },
                { "y": -2.41595741864367, "tooltipLabel": "VBA" },
                { "y": -2.26943358871165, "tooltipLabel": "VIC" },
                { "y": -0.2018974188, "tooltipLabel": "VIL" },
                { "y": -0.0854778045, "tooltipLabel": "VBS" },
                { "y": -0.0758436822, "tooltipLabel": "VES" },
                { "y": -0.0301922313, "tooltipLabel": "VTM" },
                { "y": -0.0165710193, "tooltipLabel": "MAN" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "IGA" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "LPD" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "LTK" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VAL" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VAM" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VEB" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIA" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIC" }
            ],
            "label": "Q3 19",
            "name": "Q3 19",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#f9b36c",
            "dashStyle": "Solid",
            "lineType": "Solid",
            "marker": {},
            "connectNulls": true
        },
        {
            "data": [
                { "y": -12.0603270249, "tooltipLabel": "VAS" },
                { "y": -9.16146422264508, "tooltipLabel": "PTE" },
                { "y": -3.48553644219686, "tooltipLabel": "VIC" },
                { "y": -3.32470619551604, "tooltipLabel": "VBA" },
                { "y": -2.8986080112, "tooltipLabel": "VAS" },
                { "y": -0.039319459574637, "tooltipLabel": "VBS" },
                { "y": -0.0281927712, "tooltipLabel": "MAN" },
                { "y": -0.0106122489, "tooltipLabel": "VES" },
                { "y": -0.0095501142, "tooltipLabel": "VAM" },
                { "y": -0.0072576636, "tooltipLabel": "VEB" },
                { "y": -0.0014821356, "tooltipLabel": "VTM" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "IGA" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "LPD" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "LTK" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VAL" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIA" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIC" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIL" }
            ],
            "label": "Q4 19",
            "name": "Q4 19",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#9ea2a5",
            "dashStyle": "Solid",
            "lineType": "Solid",
            "marker": {},
            "connectNulls": true
        },
        {
            "data": [
                { "y": -9.24493828517629, "tooltipLabel": "PTE" },
                { "y": -8.45456974510156, "tooltipLabel": "VAS" },
                { "y": -3.91419326549166, "tooltipLabel": "VAS" },
                { "y": -2.7262006703053, "tooltipLabel": "VBA" },
                { "y": -2.64059928262624, "tooltipLabel": "VIC" },
                { "y": -0.0721207575, "tooltipLabel": "VIL" },
                { "y": -0.027267749714351, "tooltipLabel": "VEB" },
                { "y": -0.0205519149, "tooltipLabel": "LPD" },
                { "y": -0.0057894936, "tooltipLabel": "VBS" },
                { "y": -0.0036789159, "tooltipLabel": "MAN" },
                { "y": -0.0035612511, "tooltipLabel": "VTM" },
                { "y": -0.002792625, "tooltipLabel": "VES" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "IGA" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "LTK" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VAL" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VAM" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIA" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIC" }
            ],
            "label": "Q1 20",
            "name": "Q1 20",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#95b3e1",
            "dashStyle": "Solid",
            "lineType": "Solid",
            "marker": {},
            "connectNulls": true
        },
        {
            "data": [
                { "y": -7.8038549791618, "tooltipLabel": "PTE" },
                { "y": -3.32988974998627, "tooltipLabel": "VAS" },
                { "y": -1.6977913524, "tooltipLabel": "VAS" },
                { "y": -1.5742172985, "tooltipLabel": "VIC" },
                { "y": -1.21077264323422, "tooltipLabel": "VBA" },
                { "y": -0.1701435747, "tooltipLabel": "VAM" },
                { "y": -0.0734110278, "tooltipLabel": "VIL" },
                { "y": -0.057551043, "tooltipLabel": "VES" },
                { "y": -0.0330108867, "tooltipLabel": "VTM" },
                { "y": -0.022080080685649, "tooltipLabel": "VEB" },
                { "y": -0.0122265, "tooltipLabel": "VBS" },
                { "y": -0.0082685988, "tooltipLabel": "MAN" },
                { "y": -0.0059005716, "tooltipLabel": "IGA" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "LPD" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "LTK" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VAL" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIA" },
                { "y": 0, "tooltipLabel": "VIC" }
            ],
            "label": "Q2 20",
            "name": "Q2 20",
            "type": "column",
            "color": "#cea3a6",
            "dashStyle": "Solid",
            "lineType": "Solid",
            "marker": {},
            "connectNulls": true
        }
    ]
}
```

even tried sorting the data arrays in the series by category - if that's what the highcharts documentation means by ascending X order

```
[
  {
    "y": 0,
    "tooltipLabel": "IGA"
  },
  {
    "y": 0,
    "tooltipLabel": "LPD"
  },
  {
    "y": 0,
    "tooltipLabel": "LTK"
  },
  {
    "y": -0.0666363456,
    "tooltipLabel": "MAN"
  },
  {
    "y": -7.55234464138288,
    "tooltipLabel": "PTE"
  },
  {
    "y": -0.0086822076,
    "tooltipLabel": "VAL"
  },
  {
    "y": 0,
    "tooltipLabel": "VAM"
  },
  {
    "y": -6.26724628978681,
    "tooltipLabel": "VAS"
  },
  {
    "y": -3.58044975748122,
    "tooltipLabel": "VAS"
  },
  {
    "y": -3.37783607784082,
    "tooltipLabel": "VBA"
  },
  {
    "y": -0.0160181769,
    "tooltipLabel": "VBS"
  },
  {
    "y": 0,
    "tooltipLabel": "VEB"
  },
  {
    "y": -0.0464127807,
    "tooltipLabel": "VES"
  },
  {
    "y": 0,
    "tooltipLabel": "VIA"
  },
  {
    "y": -3.1935940773000002,
    "tooltipLabel": "VIC"
  },
  {
    "y": 0,
    "tooltipLabel": "VIC"
  },
  {
    "y": -0.2846235546,
    "tooltipLabel": "VIL"
  },
  {
    "y": -0.1796231514,
    "tooltipLabel": "VTM"
  }
]
```

but that didn't change the outcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> instead highcharts seems to add to the value of the previous column for a category when drawing the stack, ending up with -5.3 + (-9.2) + (-12.0) + (-6.7) = -33.2

That's exactly how the stacking works, more information you can find here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/stacking-charts

> instead of stacking all the smaller values inside -12.0.

If you want to achieve this you shouldn't use the `stacking` feature, but set columns position to overlaps each other.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e9w4r6h8/

```
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointWidth: 20,
      groupPadding: 0.5
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.groupPadding

Comment: i see. thanks. 

> Normal stacking stacks the data series on top of each other in order

it mentions an order, what order is that? i am sorting the data by value before feeding it to highcharts but that does not seem to have any impact

Comment: @kfc - It's same order as an order of set series. First are rendering points from the first defined series, later points from the second one are added from the bottom to exist stacking, later points from the third one etc.